# Given a cube that is defined by an affine matrix how can we determin if a point is in the cube?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a affine matrix ($M_{4,4}$) that represent the position of a bounding cube. given $v = \{0,0,0,1\}$, we get the center of the cube to be $M.v = \{x, y, z, 1\}$.

How can we determine if a point $\{a, b, c\}$ is in the cube?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the vertices of the cube are not given, there is no way to tell whether a point lies inside the cube or not. However, if the cube *before transformation* is $C=[-r,\,r]^3$, the solution is easy. Given a point $\mathbf{p}=\pmatrix{a\\ b\\ c}$, calculate $M^{-1}\pmatrix{a\\ b\\ c\\ 1}=\pmatrix{\mathbf{q}\\ 1}$, where $\mathbf{q}\in\mathbb{R}^3$. Then $\mathbf{p}$ lies inside the bounding cube if and only if $\mathbf{q}\in C$, i.e. if and only if every coordinate of $\mathbf{q}$ is between $-r$ and $r$.